# Get results only over a specified min score in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using ElasticSearch to index and search for documents. I want it to only return documents that are above a specific score.

Currently, using the 7.12 Version.

I found a way to specify the minimum score [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-min-score.html) in the official documentation but it is for an older version (6.8).

Comment: This is also valid for recent versions. you can use min_score to filter your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always change the ElasticSearch Guide version in the link you shared as per requirement.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/search-search.html#search-api-min-score
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-search.html#search-api-min-score